# Should I create a table in my database to store only one element

Tags: algorithm, sorting, architecture

I am not sure if there is another option for this so if someone could give me some advice, it would be greatly appreciated!! Keep in mind, I am a new developper so don't be too harsh with the answers.

So basically I'm developing a web application and I want to give the Admin the possibility to change the email address that will receive a copy of all sent emails (*it makes sense in the case of the app*). So I got this field where I temporarily have an email address, but once the client gets the app, I want them to be able to modify this email address whenever they want to.

My question is: **Should I create a table in my database to store only this email address and thus be able to send a request to modify it when the Admin decides to or is there another way to do it?**

Edit: Tell me if I should remove the tags or if there are any better tags for this topic!

Comment: Database looks better in case of multiple server instances. File looks better for single server. Even multiple servers can have own file but that would be duplicated work to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is often a "Admin Settings" table in many applications that allows things like this in a key-value pair sort of model.

|Setting   |Value            |

++++++++++++

| ccEmail  |admin@yourapp.com

| othersetting| 3 |

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understand this, but where would I store the "admin@yourapp.com" if not in a database? I want it to be able to get modified so I would have a reference to somewhere where I would store it right?

Comment: As @Rob Conclin said, you should store it in database. But your table (`AdminTable`) should be designed with key/value columns (`setting` and `value`). Then you will insert one row `INSERT INTO ADMIN_TABLE (SETTING, VALUE) VALUES ('ccEmail','mail@mail.com')` Finally when you want to update this field you will update with WHERE clause and there you will search for `ccEmail` (`UPDATE ADMIN_TABLE SET VALUE='new@mail.com' WHERE SETTING='ccEmail'`)